# Does it matter when I repair?

Tags: diablo-iii

While playing through the higher difficulties levels, I find myself dying a whole lot (and therefore spending a whole lot of gold repairing my equipment).  On death, it says that 10% durability is lost.  Is that 10% of the remaining durability, or 10% of the original durability?  If it's the former, I would think it would make sense to wait until my equipment breaks to repair.  If it's the latter, I wouldn't think it matters.

Does the formula for calculating the cost of repairs linearly scale with how much durability is lost?  If so, that might break such a tie.

Comment: I'd never actually considered that it may be the later, but thinking back to actual playing, it does seem that may be the case. I've never actually counted, but it seems that sometimes I take a big death streak and still no broken equipment.

Comment: In World of Warcraft, when you lose 10% of the durability on your item, it's always based on the original 100% (so in this case you can die a maximum of 10 times before you have to repair). I assume this tradition is continued in D3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's 10% of the original, maximum durability.

Additionally, since the cost of repairs scales linearly with durability loss, and since item condition is a binary (either an item is broken, and contributes no stats, or it's not, and contributes all stats), it *does not matter* when you repair, so long as you do so before the first item hits 0.

Comment: Is there any additional cost when repairing a broken item, or can I repair it after it breaks for the same cost per percentage?

Comment: @DaveMcClelland No extra cost, just extra inconvenience of not being able to choose when to repair. Really, there's no reason not to just repair anytime you pass by a vendor. Make it a habit and you'll never get caught off guard with broken gear.

Comment: Salvaging weapons when they're lower in durability is more cost effective, but it's probably not worth the hassle

Comment: @DaveMcClelland Salvaging weapons good enough to actually *use* is almost never worthwhile versus vendoring or auctioning them anyway.

Comment: This is a good point

Comment: So an item with a 100/100 Durability will be 90/90 after the character dies? And 81/81 the next time?

Comment: @SabreWolfy I realize this is much, much, later - but from my understanding it goes from 90/100>80/100>70/100 etc..